# Can't understand the tree.value in this Python code

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

This is the answer for leet code question 270(Find Closest Value in BST) in Python. I could'nt grasp what and how the tree.value in this code works.

```
def findClosestValueInBst(tree, target):
    return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree, target, closest)

def findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree, target, closest):
    if tree is None:
       return Closest
    if abs(target - closest) > abs(target - tree.value):
       closest = tree.value
    if target < tree.value:
       return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree.left, target, closest)
    elif target > tree.vlaue:
       return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree.right, target, closest)
    else:
       return closest
```

Comment: In leet code, the `.value` property usually describes the value of the node.  You can confirm this by looking at the node definition in the question.  Can you show what you tried to do to solve it or figure out what `tree.value` was? Did you try printing it to check the value? Copying and pasting a solution and asking for an explanation is not what this site is meant for.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this site. I am learning algorithms and trying to solve leet code questions. I was confused with that question and the answer I saw for it. I thought I could ask help here.

Comment: Yeah it's no biggie, you'll get (at least I have) some of the best help you can on this site and find some people who will write hilariously detailed answers.  Just make sure you always post what you wrote, why it isn't working and what you tried to fix it.  Most of the time, I end up solving my own problems doing that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class for TreeNode that's defined by LeetCode, and you don't have to add that to the Solution:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None
```

This'd pass through:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def closestValue(self, root, target):
        a_value = root.val
        child = root.left if target < a_value else root.right
        if not child: 
            return a_value
        b_value = self.closestValue(child, target)
        return min((b_value, a_value), key=lambda x: abs(target - x))
```

Also, there is no `tree.value`, it should be `tree.val` I guess.

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/closest-binary-search-tree-value/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.